# Error invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: django

Estoy programando una aplicación en Django que te permite buscar Partidas arancelarias y saber los permisos que este lleva. Creando el formulario de búsqueda me sale este error: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` al cargar la pagina.

Estos son mis modelos:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Permiso(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField (max_length=50)
    direccion = models.TextField (null = True, blank = True)


    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.nombre)



class Partida(models.Model):
    partida = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    descripcion = models.TextField ()
    permisos = models.ManyToManyField (Permiso, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.partida)
```

Esta mi vista:

```
def Partida_Search(request):
    partida = request.GET.get('q','')
    context = Partida.objects.get(partida=partida)
    return render (request, 'partida/partida_search.html', {'partida': context})
```

Esta mi URL:

```
from apps.partida.views import Partida_Search
urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^buscar/$', Partida_Search, name='partida_buscar'),
]
```

Y por últimno la plantilla:

```
<h3>Partidas arancelarias</h3>
                    <form action="{% url 'partida_buscar' %}" method="get">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="text" name="q" id ="buscador" value="">

                        <button style="position:absolute;top:47px;left:375px;"
             type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
                    </form>
```

Soy nuevo en la comunidad. ¿Alguien sabe porque cuando escribo la URL `/buscar` me sale este error?:

```
    ValueError at /partida/buscar/

    invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/partida/buscar/
Django Version:     1.11.11
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:    

invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Exception Location:     /home/daniel/django-project/aranceles/apps/partida/views.py in Partida_Search, line 36
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.6.7
Python Path:    

['/home/daniel/django-project/aranceles',
 '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

Server time:    Lun, 11 Feb 2019 20:03:57 +0000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel, tu problema es que no en todos los casos existe una búsqueda. Es por eso que esto:

```
partida = request.GET.get('q','')
```

Hace que `partida` tenga el valor `''` (una cadena vacía). El problema surge cuando intentas hacer el query:

```
context = Partida.objects.get(partida=partida)
```

Ya que `partida` es un campo de tipo entero y Python no puede convertir esa cadena vacía a un entero para generar el query.

Pueden haber muchas formas de solucionar este problema, el más sencillo es agregar un bloque `try` / `except`. Recuerda también que el método `Partida.objects.get` arroja un error si el objeto que estás buscando no existe:

```
def Partida_Search(request):
    partida = request.GET.get('q', '')
    try:
        context = Partida.objects.get(partida=partida)
    except Exception:
        context = Partida.objects.none()
    return render (request, 'partida/partida_search.html', {'partida': context})
```

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto y gracias. Al final lo hice con una script de jquery ya que tenia una view que me mostraba todas las partidas en una tabala en un template y me quedo asi:

```
<script>
 // Write on keyup event of keyword input element
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#search").keyup(function(){
 _this = this;
 // Show only matching TR, hide rest of them
 $.each($("#mytable tbody tr"), function() {
 if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1)
 $(this).hide();
 else
 $(this).show();
 });
 });
});
</script>
```

Se me ajustaba mas, pero gracias igual, la probe y funciono perfectamente y la estoy usando ahora en otro proyecto.

Comment: Perdona porque me sale todo el codigo junto, es que empece nuevo en la comunidad y todavia no me adapto.